# Sharepoint site as a subsite under a asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have asp.net hosted at my domain which i access using a url like 'http://www.xyz.com. I have other web applications which are under the root web application in virtual directories which can be accessed using a url like 'http://www.xyz.com/subsite1 etc.

Now i want to have a sharepoint site as a subsite under my root website which i can access using a url like 'http://www.xyz.com/sharepointsite1.

I have installed sharepoint 2010 server.This installed a new website Sharepoint-80 and The central administration site. I have changed the Sharepoint-80 website setting to point to wwwwroot where my asp.net wesite and its subsite files are located. Now if i make a new site collection in my sharepoint site and it gets successfuly created. But when i browse it i get following error.

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

My webserver is also a domain controller. How do i resolve this issue? And how do i achieve the main aim of having a sharepoint site as a subsite under my main website?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, unless you are using different host headers or you can write an HttpModule which would be complex in my opinion. Although reverse is possible, You can have a sharepoint site at `/` and then an ASP.NET site at `/subsite`

The reason is an IIS SharePoint website is different from IIS ASP.NET website. IIS SharePoint Website registers an extra `SPRequest` module which fetches the data from SharePoint content database. When you request `/` , it will always try to pull this data from the SharePoint Content database.

In your case, where you have changed the SharePoint-80 website to point to wwwroot, you have essentially removed `SPRequest` module from the pipeline. That's the reason you get the error, because its not able to pull the content from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the other way around. Change main site to Sharepoint site, and let your other asp.net application/site to be subsite of sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Simply because you're trying to encapsulate a cloud-based system into an internal IIS folder structure.

You can not add Sharepoint online page in an iframe because of the same origin policy that most of the sites on internet adopted this days. This is mainly for security reasons to avoid from web attacks like Clickjacking and XSS.

You can not add Sharepoint online page in an iframe because of the same origin policy that most of the sites on internet adopted this days. This is mainly for security reasons to avoid from web attacks like Clickjacking and XSS.

If you want to display the content of the sharepoint online into different domain, than try to use provider hosted app in windows azure or develop a Napa sharepoint hosted app which can make cross domain requests in REST or ajax